# Why are the measured and theoretical Q factor of an LC circuit very far off?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf

I have an LC circuit, where inductance is about 5 mH, and the capacitor is about 1.25 nF. The resistance of the inductor is about 1 ohm.

I think the theoretical Q factor should be $$\frac{\sqrt{L}}{R\sqrt{C}} \approx 2000$$

I measured the Q factor by attaching an oscilloscope and function generator to the LC circuit, and then

1. found that the amplitude was maximized when I set the signal generator to 60kHz
2. measured the amplitude to be half as high at roughly 90kHz and 40kHz

Since Q is also the frequency / FWHM, the measured value is just slightly above 1, so i'm about 3 orders of magnitude off in my estimate.

I repeated the experiment with a 9.1 uF capacitor, since I think things like skin effect might change the resistance in my inductor at high frequencies (although I get the sense that 60 kHz is not all that high). This gives a theoretical Q factor of 23. The resonant frequency was 750 Hz, and the amplitude was halved at 500 and 1200 Hz, so again the measured Q factor is about 1. So, the mystery remains.

I did see there's at least one other similar question, but the asker there was only like 5% off, not 3 orders of magnitude, so I think I must be making a much more obvious mistake.

Here's my best attempt at sketching out the circuit and my measurements.
[image]

The inductor is copper wire wrapped around some sort of ferrite rod, roughly 100-200 turns.

Comment: What's the impedance of your 5 mH inductor at 60 kHz. What its ratio with R1?

Comment: There is resistance in your inductor!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat And inductance in the capacitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

R1 is dampening your circuit down and wrecking the measured Q factor. If you need to measure Q try tickling the parallel tuned circuit with a small series capacitor from the signal generator OR, just wiring L and C in series and feeding a signal from the signal generator.

R1 is effectively in parallel with your L and C and the Q factor for a parallel resistor is this: -

$$Q = R\sqrt{\dfrac{C}{L}}$$

If I put number values into the formula I get a Q of 2.5 i.e. about 3 orders of magnitude lower than you expected.

> *so i'm about 3 orders of magnitude off in my estimate.*

BINGO!!!

Comment: thank you, i think i'm a bit confused by why R1 damps the circuit: in my mind, if LC circuit is like a pendulum, then the signal generator is an external force periodically applied to the pendulum, and having a resistor there simply limits the external current (force) that is applied. however, the pendulum is still free to swing by itself -- it's not as if the resistor is between the inductor and capacitor, so it's not intuitive to me why it damps.

Comment: If you applied a current source across the parallel tuned circuit you’d see the true Q factor. Look at it another way, if the resistor in series with the voltage source became zero ohms, you wouldn’t measure any resonance.

Answer (score 5):

Your theoretical formula for Q is wrong. Let me go through it, such that you can find the expression for the Q-factor for any **linear** circuit transfer function.

### Finding Q

Call the node connected to the top end of the voltmeter \$V_{_o} \$. Adding GND to the bottom end of the voltmeter allows you to write this node equation: -
$$\frac{V_{_o}-V_{_\text{in}}}{R_{_{1}}}+\frac{V_{_o}}{Z_{_C}}+\frac{V_{_o}}{Z_{_L}}=0 \tag1 $$
Inserting the Laplace transformed expressions, \$Z_{_C}=\frac{1}{sC} \$ and \$Z_{_L}=sL \$ and solving with respect to \$V_{_o} \$ gives you the transfer function
$$\frac{V_{_o}}{V_{_\text{in}}}=\frac{\frac{1}{RC}s}{s^2+\frac{1}{RC}s+\frac{1}{LC}} 
\tag2$$
The transfer function is in standard form. We observe the expression for the damping coefficient \$\alpha = \frac{1}{2RC} \$ and for the undamped resonant frequency \$\omega_{_0}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}} \$. We can then find the damping ratio
$$\zeta = \frac{\alpha}{\omega_{_0}}=\frac{1}{2RC \sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}} \tag3$$
The Q-factor is defined as 1/(2zeta), so
$$Q=\frac{1}{2\zeta}= RC\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}} = R\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}\tag4$$
Which matches Andy's expression for Q.
Plugging in your values I get
$$Q=2.5 \: \: \text{and} \: \: \omega_{_0}=63.6 \: \text{kHz}$$

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, let me comment that you'll never see a Q of 2000 from a circuit like this. Every energy loss mechanism in the circuit reduces the Q.

The DC resistance is only part of the loss of an inductor. A 5 mH inductor is going to use a permeable core, and permeable materials have hysteresis losses. This means that a portion of magnetic energy stored in the core is dissipated as heat. Also skin effect, which increases the resistance of the copper winding with frequency, cannot generally be neglected at 60 kHz.

Capacitors also exhibit hysteresis losses.

Your signal generator isn't a perfect voltage source and your scope isn't a perfectly passive measurement device. Both will dissipate some of the energy applied to the circuit.

In practice, a Q of 100 from a passive circuit like this would mean you've done a good job of choosing low loss components and arranging minimal coupling to the measurement apparatus. A Q higher than 100 is difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according the Wikipedia the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#Bandwidth_definition) of the [Quality Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) is:

$$\text{Q}:=\frac{\text{resonance frequency}}{\text{bandwidth at half power}}\tag1$$

The transfer function of your circuit is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{sL}\text{||}\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\left(\text{sL}\text{||}\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)+\text{R}}=\frac{\text{Ls}}{\text{CLRs}^2+\text{Ls}+\text{R}}\tag2$$

Using the fact that working with sinusodial signals, we can write \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$. So for the ampltiude we get:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{L}\omega}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}-\text{CLR}\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\text{L}\omega\right)^2}}\tag3$$

We can now find the:

- Resonance frequency:
  $$\frac{\partial\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|}{\partial\omega_0}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{LC}}}\tag4$$
- Bandwidth at half power:
  $$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega_0\right)\right|\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega=\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{4\text{CR}^2}{\text{L}}}\pm1}{2\text{CR}}\tag5$$

So, for \$\text{Q}\$ we get:

$$\text{Q}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{LC}}}}{\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{4\text{CR}^2}{\text{L}}}+1}{2\text{CR}}-\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{4\text{CR}^2}{\text{L}}}-1}{2\text{CR}}}=\text{R}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\text{C}}{\text{L}}}\tag6$$